# Will Oracle optimize if using it like a key-value store?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11.2. Our usecase is like NoSQL. But still we need to persist data in Oracle. The requirement is store three columns: key, name, value.

There can be millions of key, hundreds of name, value size is about 2k~8k. Different name can have the same key value.

If I just create a table in Oracle with these three column and use Key+Name as primary key.

- Is it doable to let oracle store all rows with the same key together to same key space?
- If rows with the same key increase, will oracle keep these value together in physical storage?

Comment: I think that's proprietary information (Oracle stores the table information in datafiles, if that helps). Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "key space" .. May be you refer to the actual stored data as such, dunno .. just guessing ..

Comment: You can put that into an [index organized table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT911). Oracle will then keep the "table" physically sorted. Or you could create a [hash cluster](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT609)

Comment: See above. Look into index compression as well, that will save some space.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, "Another benefit is the avoidance of the space overhead of a separate primary key index." and "Index-organized tables are useful when related pieces of data must be stored together" is what I need. But my concern is if related pieces of data will be stored together, if a row size increased, will it be reallocated to a different place? And will it cause lots of disk fragment?